# Deserialize jagged array with unknown dimensions

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net, jagged-arrays

I'm currently trying to parse a Json file in Unity using Json.NET and can parse 80% of the data at the moment. I've come across a section that is formatted like this.

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [ 1, 1 ],
          [ 2, 2 ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "coordinates": [
        [ 1, 1 ],
        [ 2, 2 ],
        [ 3, 3 ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [ 1, 2 ],
          [ 1, 2 ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            [ 1, 2 ],
            [ 1, 2 ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The coordinates array may contain an unknown number of coordinates and it will be a jagged array with unknown dimensions as well. I'm unable to parse it as I'm not very well versed with Json deserialization.

Any help on how to approach this appreciated.

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/aug/30/using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing.  Then step through and convert to a finite data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much variety is in your data but here's a rough idea using recursion.

```cs
    void ParseCoordinateJSON()
    {
        var coordinates = new List<int[]>();
        var parsed = JObject.Parse(rawJson);

        var featureArray = parsed.SelectToken("features");
        var coordArray = featureArray.Children();

        coordArray.ToList().ForEach(n => ExtractCoordinates(n.SelectToken("coordinates"), coordinates));

        Debug.Log(string.Join("\n", coordinates.Select(c => $"({string.Join(", ", c)})")));
    }

    void ExtractCoordinates(JToken node, List<int[]> coordinates)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (node.Children().Any(n => n.Type == JTokenType.Integer))
        {
            coordinates.Add(node.Children().Select(n => n.Value<int>()).ToArray());
            return;
        }

        node.Children().Where(n => n.Type == JTokenType.Array).ToList().ForEach(n => ExtractCoordinates(n, coordinates));
    }
```

Edit:
Here's it is without linq which might be easier to follow:

```cs
void ParseCoordinateJSONNoLinq()
{
    var coordinates = new List<int[]>();
    var parsed = JObject.Parse(rawJSON);

    var featureArray = parsed.SelectToken("features");

    // These will be the objects with a "coordinates" key and an array value.
    var coordArray = featureArray.Children();

    foreach(var node in coordArray)
    {
        ExtractCoordinatesNoLinq(node.SelectToken("coordinates"), coordinates);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", coordinates.Select(c => $"({string.Join(", ", c)})")));
}

void ExtractCoordinatesNoLinq(JToken node, List<int[]> coordinates)
{
    var intValues = new List<int>();

    // Step through each child of this node and do something based on its node type.
    foreach(var child in node.Children())
    {
        // If the child is an array, call this method recursively.
        if (child.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            // Changes to the coordinates list in the recursive call will persist.
            ExtractCoordinatesNoLinq(child, coordinates);

        // The child type is an integer, add it to the int values.
        } else if (child.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
        {
            intValues.Add(child.Value<int>());
        }
    }

    // Since we found int values at this level, add them to the shared coordinates list.
    if (intValues.Count > 0)
    {
        coordinates.Add(intValues.ToArray());
    }
}
```

If the rest of your data is reliable, I would use typical data objects and de-serialize to them then add something like the above as a [Custom JSON Converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for an object representing the jagged array.

```cs
public class MyDataObject {
  public string SomeField {get; set;}

  public Vector2 Position {get; set;}

  [JsonProperty("features")]
  public JaggedFeatures {get; set;}
}

public class JaggedFeatures {
  public List<int[]> Coordinates {get; set;}
}

//...

JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyDataObject>(rawJSON, new JaggedFeaturesConverter())
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses @ataboo. I'm going to take some time to understand what's happening here tbh. One thing I may have written in the question incorrectly is the fact that the Json example is still only one section of a much larger Json, which I've managed to parse correctly. The link you posted on dynamic Json parsing has gotten me halfway there already! My solution is far from perfect, but if I do get the chance, I'll make to sure to implement you solution and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the update! That makes a lot more sense now. I'll give it a go and update here if it works, though it may take tome time as I'm finding Custom Json converters to be a little confusing. I understand their purpose, may just require some time to understand and implement.

Comment: Also marking this as the answer as it seems to be the best solution to this particular problem.